# How to restrict pages to logged in users only

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to protect some urls so users can't access them without login in first. This is my Auth.js

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{ currentUser }}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And this is my App.jsx

```
function App() {
return (
    <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route path="/citas" exact>
                    <CitasPage />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/citasDetalladas" exact>
                    <CitaDetallada />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/crearCita" exact>
                    <CrearCitasPage />
                </Route>
                <PrivateRoute path="/index" exact >
                    <Index />
                </PrivateRoute>
            </div>
        </Router>

    </AuthProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Since I'm new to React, I've been following a tutorial for doing the login and logout using Firebase and React, but it didn't help with this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this auth flow to protect routes from unauthenticated users.

I have created global context with maintain currentUser.

By this currentUser, routes are decided.

#### AuthProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";


export const AuthContext = createContext();
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } else {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setCurrentUser(null);
      }
    });
  }, [setCurrentUser, setRole, setIsLoading]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

#### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthProvider } from "./data/auth";

function App() {
return (
        <AuthProvider>
          <Router>
            <Routes />
          </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Routes.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Switch, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from "../data/auth";

const Routes = () => {
    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
if (currentUser) {
        return (    
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/dashboard' component={dashboard} />
                <Route path='/report' component={report} />
                <Route path='/profile' component={profile} />
                <Redirect to='/report' />
            </Switch>
        )
    } else {     
        return (    
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/login' component={login} />
                <Route path='/register' component={register} />
                <Redirect to='/login' />
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}
export default Routes;
```

Comment: Note that in addition to managing the navigation flow in the front-end it is absolutely necessary to implement authorization in the back-end, by using security rules. The OP does not indicate which services he uses (Firestore? RTDB?) but each service has its specific way to set-up [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something to determine whether the user is currently authenticated. I'm not sure exactly how `firebase.auth()` works but you need to check on each route (or use a higher-order component) whether the user is authenticated and if not, return `<Redirect to='somewhereElse' />`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should do that on every restricted page?